# Need Javascript to locate individual divs looped by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loops, tags

I managed to create a PHP loop that takes an array and create multiple copies of the same button while the buttons each have their own idenfication ("adiv_1" , "adiv_2", "adiv_3", etc). I have a javascript function that is able to take a single button "before it was called just 'adiv'" and change the text of the button if one clicks on it.

However due to the PHP loop which named it "adiv_1 or adiv_2 or adiv_3", I don't know how to create a javascript function that can take one of the buttons looped with a different identification div tag and get javascript to identify each one if one click on a certain button in that group. Can anyone help?

PHP loop that create the group of buttons

```
<?php

$array_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person_finder_info");

$i = 0;

while($search_row = mysql_fetch_array($array_query)){
?>
    <p><button type="button" onclick='load()'><div id='adiv_<?php echo $i?>'>Add this person</div></button></p>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Javascipt / AJAX function that changes button text (by getting echoed information in PHP file)

```
//Changes button text to "You added him!"
function load(){                                    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("adiv_1").innerHTML =      xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

    }

xmlhttp.open('GET','include.inc.php', true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rudimentary, but I think you're trying to do something like this, just loop inside of the onreadystatechange function like you did in the other one to display what you want in there to handle all of the buttons.:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) 
{
?>
    <p><button type="button" onclick='load()'><div id='adiv_<?php echo $i;?>'>Add this person</div></button></p>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
//Changes button text to "You added him!"
function load(){                                    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    <?php
    echo "var divArray = {";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) 
    {
       echo "'adiv_".$i."'".($i < $count-1 ? "," : "");
    }
    echo "};" /// after the loop this will output like var divArray = {'adiv_1','adiv_2', ... };
    ?> 

    for (var i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++) {                         
        document.getElementById(divArray[i]).innerHtml(dataFromResponse[i]); // assuming you've processed the response from AJAX into an array

    }
  }
}

xmlhttp.open('GET','include.inc.php', true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

I can't help you with setting up all of the button innerHTML though since I don't know what kind of response you're getting from AJAX. This is just to lead you in the right direction.

Comment: The new javascript has managed to give each of the button an ability to do something now. However if I click on any one of the buttons, all of the buttons change their texts regardless of whether they were clicked or not.

I suspect that this is because all buttons have the same onclick function "load()" and the loop causes all of the button onclick functions to trigger. I need only certain ones to activate rather then all of them.

Any suggestions how I should fix this?

Comment: You will have to add some javascript to handle the ajax response and make each button's innertext do something different. If you update your question with a sample of your AJAX data, then I can offer you a direction to go.

Comment: Basically the only code in "include.inc.php" is "echo 'Person added!'" But I may update the code so that it would use a mysql_query update to the database before I have it echo "Person Added!"

Comment: My edit to my answer is a bit to process, but read through it and you shoudl be able to figure out what I'm trying to do. That's not necessarily the best way to handle what you're trying to do, but it'll work. Go from there and make something better.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned this earlier, but do you mind editing the code so that it's suitable for this loop condition: $search_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_info");  and  while($search_row = mysql_fetch_array($search_query)){  }  I will edit the original post. You mind editing to adapt to and add this loop? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, gonna have to figure that one out yourself. It's moving from helping you, to writing your code for you. Your original question has been answered, if you have a mysql question, you're welcome to post a new question. Good luck.

Comment: I managed to get it to work! I was looking at your code, made some adjustments, and decided to change some things (such as adding if then statements and passing PHP variables through JS parameters). But thanks for your help!